# Does Dell Latitude 7390 13'' support Thunderbolt?

Tags: dell-latitude, thunderbolt, usb-c

I have a Dell Latitude 7390 at work. According to [this compatibility list](https://thunderbolttechnology.net/products?tid=14&field_company_nid=1279&field_prod_os_value_many_to_one=windows&field_prod_tb_version_value_many_to_one=tbv3), the device should be supported, but checking the [manufacturer's site](https://www.dell.com/en-us/work/shop/dell-laptops-and-notebooks/latitude-7390/spd/latitude-13-7390-laptop/cto04l739013us) it seems to be an option.

Checking the USB-C port, it only has the DisplayPort logo (I thought initially it was some Dell smaller logo). No Thunderbolt arrow.

Can I call it as not having Thunderbolt 3 support? Is there some way of testing if it has or not support?

Answer (score 0):

If you can access notebook’s BIOS, have a look at this:

> Systems that have optional Thunderbolt 3 capability will have a **USB/Thunderbolt configuration** option listed in the BIOS regardless of having a Thunderbolt 3 option installed.
>
> If the system **DOES NOT have Thunderbolt 3 capability**, the thunderbolt options will be grayed out and cannot be selected in the BIOS.

(From [Some Systems with USB Type-C Port Lack a Thunderbolt 3 Controller](https://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/19/sln305150/some-systems-with-usb-type-c-port-lack-a-thunderbolt-3-controller).)